# How can I make this number pattern using nested loops in C?

Tags: c, loops, nested-loops

What mistake am I making here? I'm not very good with loops, I just started off.

[image: Question]

My answer so far:

[image: My code-answer]

### Edit

Thank you so much everyone for helping out, I fixed the issue :) I'll stop posting the picture of my code from now on.

Comment: You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Comment: "What mistake am I making here?" You are posting an image of your code instead of the code. Please fix.

Comment: Your comparison operators are the wrong way around, for instance you should write `i <= n` in the outer loop. That condition must be true for the loop to continue.

Comment: Okay sorry about that, will do it next time :) @4386427

Comment: @AndreasWenzel sorry will do it from next time :)

Comment: @MahiyatNawarMantaqa you can edit your current question to include the code directly in the question (with proper formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i >= n; i++)
```

Let's translate this to english:
While i is bigger than (or equal to) n (`i >= n`), you add 1 to i (`i++`) and run what's inside the curly brackets. That's just an infinite loop. i is just going to get bigger and bigger, and will never be smaller than n, which is required for the loop to stop. (It runs **as long as** or **while** `i >= n`).
Unless `n` is `> 1` to begin with, then the loop won't even iterate once.

You got the inner loop right, but in the outer loop you have to write `i <= n` instead of `i >= n`.